# Has the exchange contract deployed to the eos mainet?

Tags: smart-contract, exchange

Has the exchange contract deployed to the eos mainet?
When will it be available ?

Comment: What is the exchange contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The exchange contract is still under development by Block one team under the supervision and guidance of Dan Larimer.

The RAM market is a live test of some of the most important new elements of the exchange, such as the bancor algorithm and its related parameters.

The exchange will be a major event for the eos blockchain and will enable much improved pegged fiat currencies with improved liquidity and reduced divergence.

The exchange is important for many future dApps which will rely on it for transactions internal to participants of tge dApp and between dApps.

The social network Block one plan and develop will depend on the exchange too.

Rest assured that tge exchange going live will be a public event and will not go unnoticed.